# Unplug laptop when upgrading?

Tags: windows, laptop, power-supply, static-discharge

Some laptop hardware upgrade/repair tutorials advise unplugging, others to keep it plugged, latter arguing it provides a continued discharge path for built-up static electricity. This reasoning makes sense, except it's also a *source* of electricity, and I'm unsure of the net effect. [This source](https://blog.macsales.com/2225-discharging-static-electricity-for-safe-computer-upgrading/) advises not unplugging *if* the laptop has a secondary power switch that's exposed when removing laptop casing, used for further draining power.

Which is accurate? Leave plugged with secondary power switch? And always remove battery?

Answer (score 1):

**Hardware repairs / upgrades:**

If you are physically repairing the machine, of course make sure it is off and the battery removed and the machine uplugged. This is very important and all the repair manuals I have say this.

**Software updates:**

If you are software repairing the machine or upgrading it, there is no need at all to remove the battery, or otherwise unplug it with the battery in place. This has been true for the many decades I and my clients have used laptops. No need.

In fact, Lenovo says have charged battery and ensure the laptop is plugged in to upgrade BIOS. The BIOS upgrade will not proceed unless it is plugged in.

You are perfectly safe to update a laptop with a battery installed and plugged into AC, and it is a very good idea in the case of a power failure

Comment: Hardware, not software. See [second bullet](https://www.howtogeek.com/169994/how-to-protect-your-pcs-hardware-from-static-electricity-when-working-on-it/), a fairly reliable source, and others agree with it. I don't have an anti-static mat, so the only laptop discharge will happen through me. There's reasoning both ways.

Comment: If you do a lot of repairs, obtain an anti static mat. I use a ground wire when dis-assembling a laptop and that works reliably.  I make sure the machine is unplugged and the battery out.

Comment: If you're working on a desktop machine, leave the power cable connected but turned off at the outlet for a good ground on the case.

Comment: @spikey_richie Haven't seen this suggestion anywhere, and it makes a good deal of sense - just ensure the power cord's unplugged from everything for a while so it discharges, then plug back into laptop but not to power outlet. Perhaps have the tips touch a wall or something.

Comment: Yeah, I usually press the power button on the case to draw the remaining current out of the PSU. Then you're good to go.